# how to access config_maps from openshift console in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, user-interface

I want to use the open shift console config_map variables in my application.
It is the host URL for my API.
I want to know the angularjs way to achieve it.
like it is in node.js

```
process.env."config_map_varibale_name"
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I went through all the ways but I did not find any. So, I landed up for achieving it through JAVA and then accessing it from the window variable in AngularJs.